# What does it mean to include/exclude tax from catalog prices?

Tags: magento-1, tax

I can set `Catalog Prices` to `Exclude Tax` or `Include Tax` from `System > Configuration > [Sales] Tax`. I notices that the formula to calculate tax based on this configuration is in `app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php:645`:

```
public function calcTaxAmount($price, $taxRate, $priceIncludeTax = false, $round = true)
{
    $taxRate = $taxRate / 100;

    if ($priceIncludeTax) {
        $amount = $price * (1 - 1 / (1 + $taxRate));
    } else {
        $amount = $price * $taxRate;
    }

    return $amount;
}
```

My problem is I can't understand the formula (`$price * (1 - 1 / (1 + $taxRate))`). What does it mean to include tax in catalog prices?

Comment: Well basically when you select price include tax at that time whatever price you include as product price magento thinks that tax is already included in that price. Like if you enter 150 and tax is 10% then magento thinks original product price is 136.36

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set the prices to include tax it means that the price you fill in the backend for a product already contains the tax.
Let's say you have a tax rule set up for `20%`
If you fill in the price for a product `60` and this includes tax, the product price will be `50`  and the tax amount will be 10.
Because `10` is `20%` of `50`.
To get a better view.

```
Total: 60 ...... means 120%  
Tax : X ........means 20%
```

you need to calculate X.  Using the proportion rule you get X  = 60 * 20 / 120 = 10.
If you got the tax value you can calculate the price without tax by subtracting the tax from the total price.  Price Excl Tax = 60 - 10 = 50.

**To explain the formula:**

Let's use the notation for the price filled in the backend as `price`. notation for tax percentage is `tax_percent` (which is below 1...as percentage).  and for price excl tax is price_excl_tax.
And you need to get the `tax_value` which is price_excl_tax * tax_percent

We get the formula.

```
price = price_excl_tax + tax_percent * price_excl_tax
```

but

```
price_excl_tax = price - tax_value.
```

We need the tax_value from the 2 above.
Replacing price_excl_tax in the first one we get.

```
price = price - tax_value + tax_percent * (price - tax_value)
```

Reducing `price` from both sides

```
tax_percent * price - tax_value * tax_percent - tax_value = 0
```

which is equivalent to

```
tax_percent * price = tax_value * (tax_percent + 1)
```

trying to solve for `tax_value` we get

```
 tax_value = tax_percent * price / (tax_percent + 1)
```

rearranging it  ...

```
 tax_value = price * (tax_percent / (1 + tax_percent))
```

which is equivalent to

```
 tax_value = price * ((tax_percent + 1 - 1) / (1 + tax_percent))
```

going further

```
 tax_value = price * (1 - 1 / (1 + tax_percent))
```

which is the formula you need.